# Is there some way to get access to Spring bean from Spock extension?

Tags: spring, testing, spock

There is an example what I want to do. 
The service client is a Spring bean, which is retrieving from external configuration class and should be called from Spock extension.

```
class ServiceCleintExtension implements IGlobalExtension {

    @Autowired
    ServiceCLient client

    @Override
    void start() {
       client.execute()
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPD**:
I've found a solution by using Spring TestExecutionListener and custom static "container" for SpecInfo/FeatureInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible, `IGlobalExtension` are initialized and manged by Spock. Furthermore, they are singletons which doesn't mesh well with multiple possible Spring contexts.

If you just want to call a method on an injected bean during setup, then I'd suggest to use an annotation based extension. Look at the builtin `AutoCleanup` extension for reference.